# I get an error when importing PCselect from pgmpy.estimators what could be the issue

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, pgmpy

I get this error when I tried importing PCselect from pgmpy:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 1
----> 1 from pgmpy.estimators import PCSelect
      2 from pgmpy.models import BayesianModel 
      3 from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

ImportError: cannot import name 'PCSelect' from 'pgmpy.estimators' (C:\Users\PC\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pgmpy\estimators\__init__.py)
```

What could be the issue

Comment: PCSelect isn't a class in pgmpy. The class for PC algorithm is just `PC`. You can import it using `from pgmpy.estimators import PC`.